# Issue with R using KNN: error 'train' and 'class' have different lengths

Tags: r, knn

I am having an issue using knn in R. When I try to run my knn I get this error:

Error in knn(train = x_train_auto, test = x_test_auto, cl = Df_census[in_train_census, :
'train' and 'class' have different lengths

I have a train and test set that includes the following variables: Age, EducYears and Sex. I have scaled Age and EducYears and one hot encoded Sex where Male =0 and Female = 1. I am trying to predict Income which has 2 values: <=50K and >50k. Here are my dimensions:

x_train_auto has dimensions of 20000, x 3
x_test_auto  has dimensions of 12561 x 3
Df_census[in_train_census, 1] has dimensions of 20000 x 1

Here is my code:

```
    predictions = knn(train = x_train_auto, # response
                      test  = x_test_auto, # response
                      cl = Df_census[in_train_census, 1], # prediction
                      k = 25)
```

Here are csv I wrote using the data in knn:

```
1. x_train_auto :<a> https://www.dropbox.com/s/aqwnj4f0k9f6h3p/x_train_auto.csv?dl=0 </a>

2. x_test_auto:  <a> https://www.dropbox.com/s/6kupkp4u4qyizy7/x_test_auto.csv?dl=0 </a>
```

3.in_train_census, 1:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/jnzpkzm0ss5f5tp/in_train_census.csv?dl=0

I am sure it is simple I am doing related to my lack of understanding of knn. I appreciate the help.

Comment: `x_train_auto` has only 2 columns, so does `x_test_auto`. What is `Df_census` ?

Comment: I see what I did. Thanks